# How can I fix font issue with a PDF file?

Tags: fonts, pdf, okular

I have a PDF file (this [Mazda owner's manual to be precise](https://instructions.cdn.mazda.media/media/mazda/e1c86_Mazda3_Owner%27s_Manual_8KK6-EE-21J_Edition2%2BL_web.pdf?)) with font issues. Therefore I cannot search within. For instance, if you search for the word `electric`, Okular cannot find it (I've also tried xpdf to no avail). But if you copy the word `electric` from the file and paste it (Okular's search bar for instance), it is shown as `Äíá2`

I can see that the file has some funky fonts which might be the cause of this issue:

[image: funky fonts]”

How can one fix this issue, so that I can search within this PDF file?

Comment: Without knowing anything about it, you have an 8 letter word which is presented as a 4 letter word to you.  This sounds like a 8-bit/character (common to us), 16-bit/character (common to asians) issue.  First thing to test is whether Adobe Acrobat does it as you expect, because you may have hit a bug in Okular

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen unfortunately Acrobat also fails. At least with Okular I can copy and search for those garbled chars. Acrobat just shows boxes and cannot even search within the file.

Comment: Sounds like this is a “for print only” PDF.   I do not have a technical solution but you may reach out to customer service and ask if they have a searchable version.

Comment: FWIW I used `qpdfview` on Ubuntu, and could search for and copy/paste "electric" with no issues.

Comment: @jos nice find!

Comment: Chrome and Preview (both on Mac) finds 18 instances of "electric".

Comment: must be something missing with my debian 12 install. because with okular, qpdfview, chrome's own reader the search results of latin chars return no results. must be also something missing with my windows 10 install as i also tried sumatra pdf viewer on windows 10 to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I would maybe check out a tool called `Xournal++` they have a pretty extensive PDF tool set. If that doesn't work `LibreOffice Draw` has some good tools as well.
Under the file properties check things like International Language settings, check MIME is us-ascii.

When making changes remember to `export` when saving, it will encode the PDF with your new settings and keep your original intact when you are testing.

You could also just run your PDF through a OCR tool and make a new document which should fix your issue. I've used a tool called ocrpdf before.

`ocrpdf` - Runs PDFs through OCR and saves the output as a text searchable PDF with the same name.